# Incorporating XSLT generated table into a webpage

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I am currently updating a webpage that has some very simple data displayed in a 2xnumberOfEntries table. The original is hard-coded into html, which, as a programmer, I find to be annoying.

I decided that converting the data to a simple XML schema would be the best idea since I really have no need for the added features of a database.

I then learned XSLT and got a working stylesheet going that converts the XML into an html table and looks fine in the browser.

Q: How do I get this new table back into the original website in place of the original table? I have tried using an iFrame, but that's outdated and unfriendly.

Sub-question: There's really nothing holding me back from using ASP.NET (I am very familiar with it) except the cost of telling my client to make the necessary server changes.  Is there a better way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This particular article](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp) explains how to do it using JavaScript (no server side dependencies).  Only caveat is, I'm not sure how this will behave on non Wintel platform.  Never tested it there.  Some browsers / environment might and might not implement it.

I'd rather [do this on the server side](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/XML/Applying-XSLT-to-XML-Using-ASP.NET/) still and inject it to a content placeholder / literal control (in ASP.NET) so not to depend on JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: W3Schools wins again. Thanks for the quick response. My only reservation is the ActiveX thing, since browsers allow users to disable that, but it seems like any time I use XSLT I get those same banners anyway. At least I now have a way to avoid hard-coding the table. Down the line I may end up binding the xml to an asp:gridview, but this solution is sufficient for now.